# Java ResultSetMetaData returning an incorrect column type

Tags: java, oracle11g

So I have been playing about with ResultSetMetaData with an oracle database.

I have came upon something odd that I can't explain.  I have a FLOAT column - defined as FLOAT(63).  When I use SQLPLUS, it confirms this is a FLOAT(63) (as does TOAD and another script in Perl I wrote) - however, when I query this column in Java using the code below, it comes back as a NUMBER(63) - is this a quirk of ResultSets or is there a config I haven't done?

Incidentally, on every other data type I have used it works perfectly -just this one is  strange.

```
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT " + column + " FROM " + schemaTable + " WHERE ROWNUM = 1");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

while(rs.next()) {   
            actualType      = rsmd.getColumnTypeName(1);
            actualPrecision = rsmd.getPrecision(1);
```

Comment: Are they not equivalent? Can you give an example of how they differ?

Comment: `NUMBER` is a floating point data type, much like `FLOAT`. I guess this is a case of a different naming convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not define *float* datatype in Oracle. You define a *real* datatype and convert it to *float* in Java.

> The recommended Java mapping for the REAL type is as a Java float.

See [more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html).

Answer (score 1):

According to the Oracle's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28285/sqlqr06.htm) :

> A FLOAT value is represented internally as NUMBER.

Probably that is the reason why `getMetaData()` returns `Number` rather than `Float`.

Comment: Just a little odd that the oracle "all_tab_column" table shows as a FLOAT as well - if this had came back with NUMBER then this would have been due to the FLOAT being represented internally as a NUMBER - not sure why this is different?